# Set custom menu folder for Adobe Air app in Linux

Tags: linux, air

After searching the web for about an hour now, I have been left empty-handed. Because of this, I'm hoping asking here will bring me a solution.

I've been using Ubuntu for some time now, and have become more reliant on Twitter to keep me notified about the changes in the world or the things which interest me. Because of this, I went searching for a good Twitter-client for Ubuntu. After some trials, I went with [Spaz](http://getspaz.com/). But one thing I noticed by this AIR-app, were the place it left its shortcut. It created an own folder under Applications (Applications -> Spaz -> Spaz). Which in my eyes is totally wrong. The correct way should be more platform integrated (Applications -> Internet -> Spaz). And not break on other platforms like Mac OS and Windows.

So, to the issue. I have been searching high and low for a good solution to be able to control where the AIR-app installs the shortcut under Ubuntu. But have yet to find the solution.

Is there a way to control this? Be able to add a shortcut in the correct place.

I've searched for information about the `programMenuFolder` attribute, trying to find some info about it. But it seems rather simple and don't have many options.

Any feedback is given my biggest gratitude.

Birger J.

***Disclaimer:** I'm not a part of the project. The developer asked me to help with a solution.*

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken all apps automatically install to the accessories directory.  Maybe you can edit the postinst.sh in the appinstall directory in adobe air itself.

This may help

http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-desktop-menu.html

This doesn't actually solve the problems for individual apps as this will install all future app menu items in the same directory.  You wouldn't want to install Tweetdeck into the  programming directory, if you get my drift.

Maybe there is something in the API that allows change for individual apps.